# How can I catch password error from configuration.buildSessionFactory (PSQL)?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

When starting Hibernate, I change my database password to a wrong password just to see how my system work.

I discover my catch block is not catching Hibernate init error when password is wrong and not throw any error. In other words, configuration.buildSessionFactory is not throwing up error.

```
try { 
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

// This not throw org.postgresql.util.PSQLException. Just print stack trace.
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

} catch (Throwable ex) { 
   // And we'll NEVER come here from configuration.buildSessionFactory error.
}
```

The Stack Trace:

```
ERROR: HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:106)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:123)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:28)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:391)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:503)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at cmabreu.infra.database.ConnFactory.getSession(ConnFactory.java:31)
    at cmabreu.infra.repositorios.BasicRepository.<init>(BasicRepository.java:19)
    at cmabreu.infra.repositorios.ConfigRepository.<init>(ConfigRepository.java:14)
    at cmabreu.services.ConfigService.<init>(ConfigService.java:16)
    at cmabreu.configurator.SingleConfig.getConfig(SingleConfig.java:21)
    at cmabreu.action.IndexAction.execute(IndexAction.java:25)
        ....
```

Comment: Just for register: When I remove `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` from `hibernate.cfg.xml` the stack trace is gone, but sill not falling in `Throwable` catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a class on the stack trace which is hiding the exception.

If you take a look on method `public void execute(Target target)` from `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate`. The `connectionHelper.getConnection();` is on nested try catch blocks. The call to this method produces the SqlException which is catch in the first try/catch block, inside the catch the stack trace is printed and the exception is throw further, however this time is catch by the second try/catch block which hides the exception. The code is shown below:

```
public void execute(Target target) {
    LOG.runningHbm2ddlSchemaUpdate();

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Writer outputFileWriter = null;

    exceptions.clear();

    try {
        DatabaseMetadata meta;
        try {
            LOG.fetchingDatabaseMetadata();
            connectionHelper.prepare( true );
            // THE SQLEXCEPTION IS THROWN <---------------
            connection = connectionHelper.getConnection();
            meta = new DatabaseMetadata( connection, dialect, configuration );
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
        }
        catch ( SQLException sqle ) {
            // THE SQLEXCEPTION IS CATCH <------------
            exceptions.add( sqle );
            // PRINTS STACK TRACE <-----------------
            LOG.unableToGetDatabaseMetadata(sqle);
            // THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN AGAIN <-----------------
            throw sqle;
        }

        LOG.updatingSchema();

        if ( outputFile != null ) {
            LOG.writingGeneratedSchemaToFile( outputFile );
            outputFileWriter = new FileWriter( outputFile );
        }

        List<SchemaUpdateScript> scripts = configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList( dialect, meta );
        for ( SchemaUpdateScript script : scripts ) {
            String formatted = formatter.format( script.getScript() );
            try {
                if ( delimiter != null ) {
                    formatted += delimiter;
                }
                if ( target.doScript() ) {
                    System.out.println( formatted );
                }
                if ( outputFile != null ) {
                    outputFileWriter.write( formatted + "\n" );
                }
                if ( target.doExport() ) {
                    LOG.debug( script.getScript() );
                    stmt.executeUpdate( formatted );
                }
            }
            catch ( SQLException e ) {
                if (!script.isQuiet()) {
                    if ( haltOnError ) {
                        throw new JDBCException( "Error during DDL export", e );
                    }
                    exceptions.add( e );
                    LOG.unsuccessful(script.getScript());
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        LOG.schemaUpdateComplete();

    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        // THE EXCEPTION IS CATCH HOWEVER THIS TIME IS NOT THROWN FURTHER           exceptions.add( e );
        LOG.unableToCompleteSchemaUpdate(e);
    }
    finally {

        try {
            if ( stmt != null ) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            connectionHelper.release();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            exceptions.add( e );
            LOG.unableToCloseConnection(e);
        }
        try {
            if( outputFileWriter != null ) {
                outputFileWriter.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            exceptions.add(e);
            LOG.unableToCloseConnection(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: You're welcome. I saw the error however I also need to read this book :).